# How to generate random symbol and get him ansii code [Python]

Tags: python, ansi

I want get ansii code for my random symbol, but I don't know how to get him.

I made symbol generator:

```
import random

string = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def random_string(count: int):
    result = ""
    for i in range(count):
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            result += random.choice(string).upper()
        else: result += random.choice(string)
    return result
```

I generate string with length 1 and want get him ansii code. How can I make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ord()** function for you targets.
Example:

```
print(ord(random_string(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrt

> *"I generate string with length 1 and want get him ansii code. How can I make this?"*

Why generate the ANSII code for **just one character**? Currently, for a `count` of 10, your code generates strings like: `funSyjVvJt` which is fine.

If you want the whole thing in ASCII, change the last `return` line to:

```py
return [ord(c) for c in result]
```

which will return values like `[88, 101, 117, 122, 101, 78, 103, 120, 99, 77]` which are the ASCII codes for the letters in `XeuzeNgxcM`.